# Create an Availability Group Listener in SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster, alwayson

I'll try to be as clear and concise as possible. I really hope someone can help me I have wasted a lot of time with this because I am not into infrastructure stuff.

Goal: Configure AlwaysOn with two SQL Server instances, connect to the database through an Availability Group Listener.

Error: [image: SQL Server Error: 19458]

Current config:

- I have two separate VMs managed with Hyper-V, in the same server.
- Both are in the same subnet.
- Both have Windows 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014 SP2 installed.
- The feature for failover clusters is enabled in both servers.
- I have created a cluster with the two nodes and one cluster network.
- I have created an Availability Group in SQL Server
- I have added both SQL Server Instances to the Availability Group
- The same domain user is an admin in both VMs.
- Firewall has been disabled in both VMs.

...but when I try to add the Availability Group Listener I get the SQL Server error 19458.

What I tried:

- I have seen that many people talk about having the same Collation in both servers: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

[Availability Group Listener - Targeting Incorrect Node](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52255639-ea7a-4385-964e-6ccde56660f2/availability-group-listener-targeting-incorrect-node?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

The secondary node had been setup with a different collation. So, I uninstalled the instance and installed it again with the correct collation. I reconfigured the nodes and the availability replicas and I still keep getting the same error.

- Then I tried with the Static IP option, but I get a different error:

[image: SQL Server error: 19456]

- I also read somewhere that it might work if I create the listener before the secondary replica. I did that but then the secondary replica can't be added because of the same error.
- It doesn't work by granting the Object Creation permission in AD as stated here [Failed to create Availability Group Listener](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/88d63dc4-6eda-4eea-a1bf-a210032bbeda/failed-to-create-availability-group-listener?forum=sqldisasterrecovery)

Maybe useful: The synchronization works as expected between the two VMs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you run cluster validation on your Windows cluster before trying to set up the AG? Based on that second error, I think your networking might be off (by the way, pictures of text are, imo, *the worst*; one of those little buttons in the lower left corner of that dialog is a "copy text" button).

Comment: yes, I have. Everything seems fine. As I said, both VMs are on the same subnet. Thanks for your reply. (sorry about the pics)

Answer (score 1):

To create the AG Listener before configure it via SSMS we ask to the network team to create a DNS name linked to a static IP then we use it to create the AG Listener (don't forget to specify Static IP when creating AG Listener)

Comment: be careful to create a witness (a file shared for example) for your Qorum's cluster configuration or you will have problem because you have only 2 nodes in your cluster (if the primary node goes down all the cluster will shutdown, there will not have a failover to the second node)